# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "student_pkey"

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Here is my stacktrace:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.5.RELEASE)

2020-11-18 14:15:41.632  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] pl.umcs.lessonwiz.LessonwizApplication   : Starting LessonwizApplication on DESKTOP-4VPS8T4 with PID 352 (C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\lessonwiz\build\classes\java\main started
by admin in C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\lessonwiz)
2020-11-18 14:15:41.634  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] pl.umcs.lessonwiz.LessonwizApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-11-18 14:15:41.678  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-11-18 14:15:41.679  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-11-18 14:15:42.249  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-11-18 14:15:42.303  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 45ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-11-18 14:15:42.861  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-11-18 14:15:42.872  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-11-18 14:15:42.872  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]
2020-11-18 14:15:42.971  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-11-18 14:15:42.971  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1292 ms
2020-11-18 14:15:43.063  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-11-18 14:15:43.182  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-11-18 14:15:43.472  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-11-18 14:15:43.571  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-11-18 14:15:43.613  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-11-18 14:15:43.647  WARN 352 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configu
re spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-11-18 14:15:43.670  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.22.Final
2020-11-18 14:15:43.829  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-11-18 14:15:43.890  WARN 352 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2020-11-18 14:15:43.956  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2020-11-18 14:15:43.994  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-11-18 14:15:43.995  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositoriesů
2020-11-18 14:15:44.823  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-11-18 14:15:44.831  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-11-18 14:15:44.979  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-11-18 14:15:44.986  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] pl.umcs.lessonwiz.LessonwizApplication   : Started LessonwizApplication in 3.671 seconds (JVM running for 4.113)
Test method
Student{id=0, albumNumber='291222', firstName='AAAAA', lastName='AAAAA', semesterId=1}
Student{id=0, albumNumber='291222', firstName='BBBBB', lastName='BBBBB', semesterId=1}
2020-11-18 14:15:45.036  WARN 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2020-11-18 14:15:45.037 ERROR 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "student_pkey"
  Szczegˇ│y: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
2020-11-18 14:15:45.052 ERROR 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [student_pkey]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:298) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELE
ASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at pl.umcs.lessonwiz.Test.test(Test.java:32) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:305) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:190) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:108) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:77) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at pl.umcs.lessonwiz.LessonwizApplication.main(LessonwizApplication.java:14) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3158) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3764) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "student_pkey"
  Szczegˇ│y: Key (id)=(1) already exists.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.22.Final.jar:5.4.22.Final]
        ... 82 common frames omitted

2020-11-18 14:15:45.124  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-11-18 14:15:45.126  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-11-18 14:15:45.127  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-11-18 14:15:45.134  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Student table:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  id serial,
  album_number varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  first_name varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  semester_id integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Student Entity:
student_id_seq is set to auto-increment by default

```
package pl.umcs.lessonwiz.domain;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student{

    public Student(String albumNumber, String firstName, String secondName, int semesterId) {
        this.albumNumber = albumNumber;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = secondName;
        this.semesterId = semesterId;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(length = 7)
    private String albumNumber;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(length = 24)
    private String firstName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(length = 40)
    private String lastName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int semesterId;

    /*
    ----------- LATER -------------
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    int semestrId;

     */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", albumNumber='" + albumNumber + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", semesterId=" + semesterId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

postgres console(These students are created by sql script):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfvjQ.png)

I also tried generate like this but this did not help

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "student_id_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "student_id_generator", sequenceName = "student_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
```

I used postgresql
It seems like I have problems with Id Generator, thanks for your ideas and answers

Comment: It happens when i try to add record to my DB

Comment: Where is the code that adds rows? You are apparently attempting to insert rows with the same primary key.

Comment: Only that 2 small classes https://pastebin.com/b01uSrEw

Comment: Yes that is prob the reason, but I wanted to know why

Comment: The problems with the sequence are probably the manually inserted students. You have to set the current value of the sequence, see https://gist.github.com/henriquemenezes/962829815e8e7875f5f4376133b2f209

Comment: Thank you Turo that was a problem. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing the following query in your database to update the value of the sequence:

```
SELECT setval('student_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM student)+1);
```

And model the entity as follows:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "student_id_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "student_id_generator", sequenceName = "student_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Integer id;
```

It is important to set the type of the ID as non-primitive to be able to set null values, the sequence will already generate the id.